# Comparing record between less than or greater than record using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My question is compare the record between `<=` and `>=` 
my table contain columns ID,Name,Address,Stacks,StartDateTime,EndDateTime.
I want to fetch record between `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime`.
DateTime Format is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

```
mysql-> Select * from Table_nm where  StartDateTime>= $DATETIME and EndDateTime<= $DATETIME1;
```

So,my question is How I compare records that,

```
1. $DATETIME= 2015-02-03 10:00:00 and $DATETIME1 =2015-02-06 20:00:00 
2. $DATETIME= 2015-02-03 05:00:00 and $DATETIME1 =2015-02-06 13:00:00
3. $DATETIME= 2015-02-03 10:00:00 and $DATETIME1 =2015-02-06 11:00:00
```

like wise records contains datetime,
so ,Give me results for filter shown below.

```
1.If I want to filter record where StartDateTime>=2015-02-03 00:00:00 and EndDateTime<= 2015-02-06 00:00:00.
2.If I want to filter record where StartDateTime>=2015-02-03 09:00:00 and EndDateTime<= 2015-02-06 12:00:00.
3.If I want to filter record where StartDateTime>=2015-02-03 01:00:00 and EndDateTime<= 2015-02-06 22:00:00.
```

and How this filter for works for DateTime `>=` and `<=` , Please help!

Comment: show me your result as well that whats the result when you run the above query

Comment: yes that'll work, if there are indeed rows that fulfil that condition

Comment: Yes It Works,But I want How to take comparison on back end in mysql. meance , I want to search See (2 no.) record. That time It shows only the time range between this time range? and see f(1 no.) record. I search It for Time 12 to 12 Is it shows between all record or only shows whoes time is `=` to 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

I use `TIMESTAMPDIFF`

In your example, it would be something like:

```
mysql-> Select * from Table_nm
        where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `StartDateTime`, '$DATETIME')>= 0
          and TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `EndDateTime`, '$DATETIME1')<= 0;
```

Comment: How it works, It shows only the record between Start date and end date and Start time and End time?

Comment: that's what it should do, try it out.

Comment: and If suppose I use function(TIMESTAMP("2015-02-03","10:00:00"),seconds) >= like this ,Then?

Comment: There may be many solutions. You can try the one I posted or figure out another way.

Comment: nope !not exact record..It shows Diffrent value too. near StartDateTime column and End DateTIme column.

Comment: Can you post the query and the result?